# Linker error while building from source code

Tags: c++, cmake, linux-mint

I am trying to build an application from source. I am able to configure it using 'cmake .'. However, when I run 'make' it gives me this:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/lux64/Release/od_batch_launcher
../../bin/lux64/Release/libBasic.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
../../bin/lux64/Release/libBasic.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
../../bin/lux64/Release/libBasic.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
../../bin/lux64/Release/libBasic.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
../../bin/lux64/Release/libBasic.so: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/lux64/Release/od_batch_launcher] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/Basic/CMakeFiles/od_batch_launcher.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I understand that its is unable to dynamically link to a c++ library. I don't quite know how to make the necessary changes to cmake. I am running gcc version: 4.9.2 on Linux Mint 17. I would be grateful for any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-ldl` to the CMake executable. To change the CMake build scripts, add something like:

```
target_link_libraries(target_name dl)
```

where `target_name` is basically the executable name without any extensions (e.g. `.exe`).

**EDIT:** Actually, I just reread you question, and I'm putting this in the wrong place. You really want:

```
target_link_libraries(Basic dl)
```

Apparently, there were also pthread-related errors, so you'd also have to add:

```
target_compile_options(Basic PUBLIC -pthread)
```

Both of these go in whichever file contains `add_library(Basic)` (usually `CMakeLists.txt`).

**EDIT 2:** Instead of `target_compile_options`, try:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
```

Comment: Thanks. So i should add target_link_libraries(target_name dl) in the CMakeLists.txt? and the target_name would be od_batch_launcher? Sorry, I'm not very comfortable with CMake.

Comment: Great! Some progress!! The errors related to 'dlopen',etc; are gone. However I'm unable to add target_compile_options. I get this : CMake Error at src/Basic/CMakeLists.txt:116 (target_compile_options):
  target_compile_options called with invalid arguments

Comment: Thank you! adding PUBLIC as well allowed cmake to go through. However, I still get: ./../bin/lux64/Release/libBasic.so: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask' when I run make.

Comment: @user2984140 Can you try using `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")` instead of `target_compile_options`?